# Remove Last entry then print it out when map<Integer, String>

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

Like title says how do I remove the Last entry in a treemap if it's sorted by `<Integer, String>`
since the `remove()` method in treemap only delete` a key...

Look like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= 10) {
    System.out.println("Value is: " + Resultat.lastEntry());
    i++;
    // here, I want to delete the last entry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [NavigableMap.pollLastEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#pollLastEntry%28%29) -removes and returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key in this map, or null if the map is empty.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> map=new  TreeMap<>();
map.put(1, "one");
System.out.println(map);

map.pollLastEntry(); // It wil remove last entry.
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pollLastEntry()` ?

> Removes and returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest
>   key in this map, or null if the map is empty.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    TreeMap<Integer, String> testTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();

    //Populate example map with values
    testTreeMap.put(1,"Test");
    testTreeMap.put(0, "Test0");
    testTreeMap.put(6, "Test6");
    testTreeMap.put(4, "Test4");
    testTreeMap.put(2, "Test2");
    testTreeMap.put(3, "Test3");
    testTreeMap.put(5, "Test5");

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 3) {
        System.out.println("Value is: " + testTreeMap.pollLastEntry());
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(testTreeMap);
}
```

Output :

```
Value is: 6=Test6
Value is: 5=Test5
Value is: 4=Test4
Value is: 3=Test3
{0=Test0, 1=Test, 2=Test2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map.remove()`; if you know the key of the last key value pair.

```
Map<Integer,String> map=new TreeMap<>();
map.remove("key");// key of last entry.
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code is here

```
     int j = 0;
    while (j <= 3) {
        Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry = records.pollLastEntry();
        records.remove(entry.getKey());
        j++;
    }
```